# On the Number of Consecutive Leading $0$s in $1/N$ and $(1/N)_{b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, periodic-functions, decimal-expansion

Let $N > 10$ be an integer.

Let $N_{b}$ be its base-$b$ representation.

Consider the decimal expansions of $\frac{1}{N}$ and $\left( \frac{1}{N} \right)_{b}$.

(1) Will there be $\lfloor \log n \rfloor$  and $\lfloor \log_{b} n \rfloor$  consecutive zeros immediately following the decimal point of $\frac{1}{N}$ and $\left( \frac{1}{N} \right)_{b}$, respectively?

(2) If so, how would one prove this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There would be $m$ consecutive zeros following the decimal point of a number $x \in [0, 1)$ in base $b$ iff $$0.1_b=\frac{1}{b} \le x \cdot b^m < 1$$

Or in other words, if the number created by shifting the decimal point right $m$ times would be exactly one more right shift from being above $1$, then $m$ is the number of consecutive zeros following the decimal point.

This means that $\frac{1}{bx} \le b^m \to m\ge \log_b\left( \frac{1}{bx}\right)$. Since we are trying to find the minimal integer value of $m$ satisfying this condition, we can take the ceiling to get $$m = \left\lceil\log_b\left( \frac{1}{bx}\right)\right\rceil = \left\lceil -1+\log_{b}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right\rceil$$

Since $x = \frac{1}{N}$, this is $$\left\lceil -1+\log_{b}\left(N\right) \right\rceil$$
which would only disagree with your results when $N$ is an integer power of $b$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know, offhand, if the $m$ consecutive zeros can occur again within the repetend, or will that sequence of zeros only occur when $x$ begins to repeat itself?

Comment: @user686782 For the $m$ consecutive zeros to all be part of the repeating part of the fraction, then a) the fraction has to repeat in base $b$, and b) the fraction has to be representable as $(0.\overline{00...0d_1d_2...d_k})_b$.

Comment: @ Varun Vejalla Right. But let me rephrase the question based on  your comment---In base b, can $m$ consecutive zeros also appear somewhere in $d_{1}d_{2}...d_{k}$, or will they not appear again until the repetend repeats itself? If the answer is $yes$, I would be extremely interested to know under what conditions they will not ever appear again in the repetend. Thanks again.